# What's the function of this component grouping connected to these RAM chips?

Tags: circuit-analysis

What's the function of this component grouping connected to these RAM chips?

[image: yamaha_dx7_dx9.pdf schematic]

Answer (score 2):

That's part of the battery backup system of a Yamaha DX7 synthesizer.

It disables the CPU access to SRAM and disconnects the supply voltage when it is too low for the CPU to be working properly.

The SRAM chip then left disabled with the battery powering it.

Comment: Justme, Thanks for the explanation